# Changing RenderTransform calls ArrangeOverride even though it shouldn't

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom panel Foo that has another custom panel Bar as it's child.

When the user moves the mouse, Foo calls a method 'Update' on Bar that causes bar to set it's renderTransform to something different.

When I did this, the ArrangeOverride method in Bar is called (not on Foo), I am confused why this is happening as no layout changes would need to be made. Is this deliberate or some kind of bug?

Comment: You change the render transform on Bar but you don't expect any re arrange of Bar?

Comment: You should assign a single `Transform` instance to `RenderTransform` initially but then change the properties of the transform itself as the mouse moves. That should NOT cause a layout pass.

Comment: Since Dominic wrote that arrange override, he could put whatever code he likes in there and not do the parts he doesn't want to happen under whichever circumstance suits his purpose.

Comment: Thanks @PeterMoore, I didn't realize the reassignment triggered this. So I'll try to modify the existing render transform rather than replacing?

Comment: Exactly right. So for example if you're using a `TranslateTransform`, just change the X and Y properties on that. Note the Transform's properties are usually bindable so you can do this easily in XAML.. What many people do is instantiate the Transform in XAML itself and use data binding against the relevant transform properties. Let me know if you can't find a good example.

Comment: Thankyou, though I'm still have an issue in that if I create a MatrixTransform foo and point renderTransform to that, I can't seem to find an in place method of modifying foo.Matrix. Using foo.matrix.offsetx etc gives me a 'not a variable' error and reassigning the foo.matrix works but still triggers ArrangeOverride. Feeling a little stuck haha.

Comment: @DominicNewman if you assign a `MatrixTransform`, you can dynamically change the `Matrix` property of that `MatrixTransform`. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.matrix?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) Are you saying you tried that and it DID create a layout pass? That is surprising. If you're just tracking the mouse though you can use a `TranslateTransform`. Anyway I suggest you post a new question showing your code and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the reference source code for UIElement.Rendertransform.

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=rendertransform

```
    [CommonDependencyProperty]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RenderTransformProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                            "RenderTransform",
                            typeof(Transform),
                            typeof(UIElement),
                            new PropertyMetadata(
                                        Transform.Identity,
                                        new PropertyChangedCallback(RenderTransform_Changed)));


    /// <summary>
    /// The RenderTransform property defines the transform that will be applied to UIElement during rendering of its content.
    /// This transform does not affect layout of the panel into which the UIElement is nested - the layout does not take this
    /// transform into account to determine the location and RenderSize of the UIElement.
    /// </summary>
    public Transform RenderTransform
    {
        get { return (Transform) GetValue(RenderTransformProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RenderTransformProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void RenderTransform_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement uie = (UIElement)d;

        //if never measured, then nothing to do, it should be measured at some point
        if(!uie.NeverMeasured && !uie.NeverArranged)
        {
            // If the change is simply a subproperty change, there is no
            //  need to Arrange. (which combines RenderTransform with all the
            //  other transforms.)
            if (!e.IsASubPropertyChange)
            {
                uie.InvalidateArrange();
                uie.AreTransformsClean = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Changing the property of a uielement which has already been measure-arranged will call InvalidateArrange on that uielement.

That will result in arrange being called.

We don't know enough about your code to suggest a specific better way, but then that isn't the question. You'd need to ensure you changed a sub property or ensure calling ArrangeOverride didn't matter or ( I guess less practical ) avoid the layout pass in your parent panel until the change is made.

Maybe you could just add an IgnoreArrange flag to Bar. Default that to false. Set it true before changing the transform, false after and return out your ArrangeOverride if true.

Bottom line is that it is that code above is causing what you're seeing.

Comment: Only `if (!e.IsASubPropertyChange)`. OP should change the appropriate properties of an existing RenderTransform object instead of assigning a new one - if that is what they are doing. Change e.g. the Matrix property of a MatrixTransform.

Comment: Or maybe hold off on the layout pass in the parent panel. I thought showing the actual code being called might help.

Comment: @Clemens that's obviously what he wants/needs to be doing. I don't know why you would vote to close rather than just provide that answer.

Comment: @PeterMoore That is not at all obvious. The question is missing a reproducible example.

Comment: The question isn't asking "how do I fix this" it's asking why that arrange happens. It is happening because that's what the callback on rendertransform property does when it changes. As shown in the code. I am a bit confused why that isn't the definitive answer actually.